# Laravel : add section only if it exists in child

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I've defined an `app.blade.php` containing header ,footer , and a section for content:

```
<html>
<head>
....
<title>@yield('title')<title>
<meta type='description' content="@yield('description')">
...
</head>
<body>
..
@yield('content')
..
</body>
</html>
```

in all child blade that i extend `app.blade` i have to define a value for `description` , else it will be empty and google would show no description for it in search results:

```
 @extend('app')
    @section('title','a title')
    @section('description','something')
    @section('content')
     ....
    @endsection
```

how can i prevent `description` meta to be included in head , when i have not defined it in child blade that has extended `app.blade`?

Answer (score 1):

i should use `hasSection` directive , as described [here](https://laravel.io/forum/02-06-2014-check-if-yieldsomething-is-set)